# libheif-dev dependencies problems with humble on Mint

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, linuxmint

if I run `sudo apt install ros-humble-desktop` (with the ROS 2 apt sources updated) I get:
`libheif-dev : depends on: libheif1 (= 1.12.0-2build1) but version 1.14.2-1ubuntu1 is going to be installed.`

(libheif1 1.14.2 is actually already installed)

I don't see this issue mentioned anywhere

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Please make sure you have executed `sudo apt update -y && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y` before installing ROS.

Comment: Yes I did, and it's a fresh new install

Answer (score 1):

Solved by

- manually downloading [libheif-dev_1.14.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb](https://mint.pkgs.org/21.2/mint-backport-amd64/libheif-dev_1.14.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb.html)
- `sudo apt install libaom-dev libdav1d-dev libde265-dev libx265-dev`
- `sudo dpkg -i libheif-dev_1.14.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb`
- `sudo apt install ros-humble-desktop`

hope this helps others, it seems a packaging bug